# Find complexity of below algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'am having algorithms lectures on C++ in university and at the moment we are on theme "Dynamic programming" and we were given three algorithms for examples, yet no additional information for them like: time complexity, memory memory usage only the code was provided without the name of the given algorithm.

I've been trying to seek them out and i managed to find only one of the three, witch turns out to be some moded version of [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) but didn't had much luck with the other ones.

I suppose the other two codes are also an modification of an well known algorithm, so if somwone recognises them, please, tell me the name I will find complexity details and how it works in depth myself.

```
    int t[MAXN],s[MAXN],M[MAXN]; 
    void restore(int i)
    { 
      if(i==1) {printf("(1) ");return;} 
      if(i==2)
      {  if(M[2]== t[1]+t[2]) 
         { printf("(1) (2) ");return;} 
         else { printf("(1 2) " );return;};
    }
    if(M[i]==t[i]+M[i-1]) 
    { restore(i-1); printf("(%d) ",i);} 
    else 
    {restore(i-2); printf("(%d %d) ",i-1,i);}
   }
```

Here is the first code.

```
    int G[MAXN][MAXN]; //сп. на съседите
    int H[MAXN][MAXN]; //сп. на предшеств.
    int L[MAXN],N, s[MAXN];//топ. сортирани върхове 
    void opt()
    {   top_sort(G,s);//
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
        { int k=s[i]; L[k]=0;
          if(H[k][0]!=0)
          { for(int j=1;j<=H[k][0];j++)
              if(L[H[k][j]]>L[k]) L[k]=L[H[k][j]];
            L[k]++; 
          }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I suppose the idea is that you work out the complexity by looking at the code, instead of by knowing the algorithm and looking it up in a book. Have you tried doing that? Did you get stuck? Might be more productive to ask about that topic instead.

Comment: yeah this was the idea but I am pretty stuck and can't find it by looking,that's why i am searching them.

Comment: It's impossible to determine the complexity if not all the code is known (what's the complexity of `top_sort()`?).

Comment: No code was provided for `top_sort()` (no idea why)

Comment: top_sort is presumably [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Comment: Yeah but... finding out the answer is not very useful. Knowing how to analyze algorithms, is. Learn how instead.